# Printing a DockPanel and fitting it to page

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I am currently wasting a ridiculous amount of paper trying to figure this out. I have a Dockpanel named Dock with stackpanels, borders and textboxes and I want the entire dock to print to one page.

```
    Private Sub Button_Click_1(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    'Define Printer Dialog
    Dim dialog As New PrintDialog
    'Define Printer Capabilities
    Dim capabil As PrintCapabilities = dialog.PrintQueue.GetPrintCapabilities(dialog.PrintTicket)
    'Scale content to capabilities of printer
    Dim scale As Double = Math.Min(capabil.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth / Dock.ActualWidth, capabil.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight /
                Dock.ActualHeight)
    Dock.LayoutTransform = New ScaleTransform(scale, scale)
    'Create a margin
    Dim pagemargin As Integer = 20
    'Define the size of the page
    Dim pagesize As New Size(capabil.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth - pagemargin, capabil.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight - pagemargin)
    Dock.Measure(pagesize)
    'Resize dock to optimal page size
    Dock.Arrange(New Rect(New Point(capabil.PageImageableArea.OriginWidth, capabil.PageImageableArea.OriginHeight), pagesize))
    'Prompt and Print
    If dialog.ShowDialog = True Then
        dialog.PrintVisual(Dock, "Printed Page.")
    End If
End Sub
```

Am I not understanding the math behind this? Is there another way I should be approaching this?

EDIT: The problem I am facing is that even though the dock seems to be sized correctly there is a huge left and bottom margin when it prints. I've tried tweaking the margin but it still seems like the start point is off. The page is also being cut-off on the top and right.

Comment: Do you think you could elaborate on what's wrong with what you've got so far?

Comment: @Doc Sorry about that, will update shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I came up with using some cues from [PageMediaSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printticket.pagemediasize.aspx).  This may or may not be what you're looking for, but it could give you some ideas in any case:

```
Private Sub Button_Click_1(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
  Dim dialog As New PrintDialog
  If dialog.ShowDialog = True Then
    Dim dockParent As StackPanel = Dock.Parent
    dockParent.Children.Remove(Dock)

    Dim vis = PerformTransform(Dock, dialog.PrintQueue)
    dialog.PrintVisual(vis, "Printed Page.")

    vis.Children.Remove(Dock)
    dockParent.Children.Add(Dock)
  End If
End Sub

Private Function PerformTransform(v As Visual, pq As PrintQueue) As ContainerVisual
  Dim root As ContainerVisual = New ContainerVisual()
  Const inch As Double = 96 'DPI

  'Set the margins
  Dim xMargin = 1.25 * inch
  Dim yMargin = 1 * inch

  'Get the user print ticket and media dimensions
  Dim pt = pq.UserPrintTicket()
  Dim printableWidth = pt.PageMediaSize.Width.Value
  Dim printableHeight = pt.PageMediaSize.Height.Value

  Dim xScale = (printableWidth - xMargin * 2) / printableWidth
  Dim yScale = (printableHeight - yMargin * 2) / printableHeight

  root.Children.Add(v)
  root.Transform = New MatrixTransform(xScale, 0, 0, yScale, xMargin, yMargin)

  Return root
End Function
```

Comment: Not quite there but it's definitely a step in the right direction. I'll continue to play with the margins until I can get it right.

Comment: The big problem I'm still running into is the huge margin from the left and bottom sides of the page. How do I define where on the page to start the printing?

Comment: @GamerJ5  It's strange that's happening for you because I don't get much of a margin at all.  I'm not able to run some tests tonight, but maybe it's based on your user settings.  I would check out the `pt` variable in the debugger and see what it actually contains.  It seems to be based on your machine's print settings.

Comment: I think I figured it out. This is all being presented inside of a frame and to the left of the frame is a scrollviewer containing navigation buttons. Even though I'm not calling it to print any of this it seems to be using that space when calculating the print area. Is there another way to measure the dock itself where it won't include any parent information?

Comment: @GamerJ5 Well, using the above code the dock is pulled out of its container before printing...  Maybe you'd need to use `Measure` and `Rearrange` in the `PerformTransform` function.

Comment: Yeah, I opened it as it's own separate window and it is still doing this. I've tried on two different printers with the same result.

Comment: figured it out, possibly very stupid on my part. For some reason it takes the alignment of the dock into account, i had left it at default but my problems all went away when I switched it to a left align. Thanks for all the help!